# jQuery Mouseover on Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I code a responsive website with Bootstrap and I do an Mouseover with jQuery on images in desktop but on Ipad when I click on those images my function Mouseover works so there is a bug.

I want in my ipad website this function Mouseover doesn't launch. How I do that?

this is my code :

```
  $('.image a img').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
  });

  $('.texte').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try the answer found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

```
if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
  $('.image a img').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
  });

  $('.texte').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
  });
}
```